# Loop through SQL query to add another information field onto the result set for each id in the row

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

How best to tackle this is SQL Server:

```
SELECT   
     APPT_ID  
    ,PATIENT_ID  
    ,APPT_DATETIME  
    ,APPT_STATUS  
FROM 
    APPT_TABLE  
WHERE 
    APPT_STATUS = 'Cancelled'
```

Output:

```
APPT_ID     PATIENT_ID  APPT_DATETIME       APPT_STATUS  
-------------------------------------------------------
1           12345       2022-07-01 10:30    Cancelled  
2           56789       2022-07-02 11:45    Cancelled  
3           11223       2022-07-02 11:45    Cancelled   
4           11224       2022-07-02 11:45    Cancelled
```

Based on data from the same `APPT_TABLE` I want the next appt booked after the `Cancelled` one - so result should look like this:

```
APPT_ID     PATIENT_ID  APPT_DATETIME       APPT_STATUS NEXT_APPT_DATETIME  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           12345       2022-07-01 10:30    Cancelled   2022-07-15 09:00  
2           56789       2022-07-02 11:45    Cancelled   2022-07-05 11:00  
3           11223       2022-07-02 11:45    Cancelled   NULL        (i.e. no next appt)  
4           11224       2022-07-02 11:45    Cancelled   2022-07-02 11:45
```

Comment: You seem to have typos or unexplained logic. In your desired output, I do not understand the logic you use for NEXT_APPT_DATETIME. There is no July 15 or July 5 value in the original data.  And do you not need something that ties a series of appointment rows together to determine the "next" one? Can a person make appointments for different "tasks" that occur within the same timeframe?

Comment: `(select min(APPT_DATETIME) from APPT_TABLE t2 where t2.PATIENT_ID = APPT_TABLE.PATIENT_ID and t2.APPT_STATUS = 'Booked' /* or whatever */) as NEXT_APPT_TIME`

Comment: You are asking for help to solve what you want, but you do not display any attempt of trying yourself, you should do this first, then get help on what you tried if it doesn't work. This is not a fix my problems so i don't have to kind of site, but a help me when i struggle with some concrete problems kind of site, from idea. read guidelines if in doubt :) please update with what you tried to motivate the helpers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the next appt, if any, is another row in the same table, then the LEAD window function might help.
The code example below will determine next_appt_datetime as the appt_datetime subsequent to the cancelled appt for the patient concerned.

```
with APPT_TABLE as (
    select
        *
    from ( values
        ('01','0001','2022-01-01','Cancelled'),
        ('02','0002','2022-01-11','Cancelled'),
        ('03','0001','2022-01-21','Normal'),
        ('04','0003','2022-01-31','Normal'),
        ('05','0003','2022-02-01','Cancelled'),
        ('06','0004','2022-02-01','Normal')
    ) vals(
        APPT_ID  
        ,PATIENT_ID  
        ,APPT_DATETIME  
        ,APPT_STATUS  
    )
)
,
allappt as (
    SELECT   
         APPT_ID  
        ,PATIENT_ID  
        ,APPT_DATETIME  
        ,APPT_STATUS  
        ,NEXT_APPT_DATETIME = lead(APPT_DATETIME) over (
                partition by PATIENT_ID
                order by APPT_DATETIME
            )
    FROM 
        APPT_TABLE
)
select
    *
from allappt
WHERE 
    APPT_STATUS = 'Cancelled'
```

Output

| APPT_ID | PATIENT_ID | APPT_DATETIME | APPT_STATUS | NEXT_APPT_DATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0001 | 2022-01-01 | Cancelled | 2022-01-21 |
| 02 | 0002 | 2022-01-11 | Cancelled | NULL |
| 05 | 0003 | 2022-02-01 | Cancelled | NULL |